# Show that input in list is editable

Tags: usability, input-fields, edit

I have a list with items that can be changed. 
When the user clicks on the item, it can be edited.

[image: editable list]

**Which is the most intuitive way to show the user, that (s)he can edit the items?**

Following options come to my mind:

1. Show an [edit icon](https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/217-2173108_edit-write-pencil-pen-page-text-editing-application.png) when the cursor is over an item
2. Always show an edit icon. When the user clicks it, the item text field is highlighted
3. Show a gray frame when the cursor is over an item
4. Show a gray square when the cursor is over an item
5. Leave it as it is

Answer (score 1):

**First**

I use Notion to manage my tasks, what they do is to change the text cursor type, like the one you are showing, and also to show the options on the start of the text, like the example below.

[image]

Maybe you could combine and show the delete icon on hover to give the sensation that there is more to do when hovered.

**Second**

If you let the delete icon permanent, I would suggest to follow the line with icon buttons and would put an edit icon besides the delete icon.

**Third**

Sometimes you can set a small hint text before the list explaining that the user can edit inline if he clicks on the text. My customers are generally old office guys, so I tend to make really clear the actions that they can do.